# Working with module libraries on Android

Tags: android

I need to create a generic application that will work with different languages (not localized per device settings) and different drawables.
The development is done using intelliJ.

My question is whether it is possible to create the "generic" app in a specific module, have a library modules and drawable module for the different languages/drawables.
Then, I'll use different compilations (with ANT) to build the different apps (for example, english with dark style images or spanish with white style images).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if this will help you, or if I understand your question but I'm currently developing an **android application that dynamically loads separate modules.**

Therefore I have my main android application that loads methods from .class files found in android jars (modules). I guess this would take care of the "generic app" part?
Handling different languages - is not something I've really looked into myself, so I can't specify how to handle that.

**Here's how my app works:**

Modules contain all the logic required to tell my main application how to behave -what views look like, switching between views, taking user input, connection to a server through a static library shared between my modules and my main application.

Though I have found a way to dynamically load images from my modules, I am still yet to find a way to dynamically load "android layouts", so my modules pull layout files and call inflaters in order to load views, or create them from scratch pro grammatically..

My modules don't contain any "activity" classes and therefore need no generation of an Android ManifestFile.

Due to this my main application needs to have no knowledge of the number or name of "activities" to put in its android manifest file because there are none- therefore I can have as many modules as I wish - all with different functionality that the main android application has NO knowledge of.

I found your question because I was looking for a way to build my modules, quick and dirty without having to use the eclipse IDE each time to create a jar.
Right now my modules need to contain the following:

.class files
a .dex file generated from the .class files
a customized manifest file.
images required for customized views

Sorry if my answer didn't really help you...